# What is the difference between "why are there same things written on this page?" and "why are same things written on this page"?

Tags: grammar

I am reading something from a book. And there is a page on which most of things is repeated. So my question is which sentence is correct:-
"Why are there same things written on this page?"
"Why are same things written on this page?"

Comment: Neither is correct.

Comment: That's about the combination of "there is/are" with the passive voice and the simultaneous use of "to be" for both purposes.

Comment: killing Time then how to say correctly?